# Adjusting Windows time drift without internet on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, time

I have Windows Server 2003 on a local LAN that has no internet connection, and need somewhat accurate timing.

Unfortunately currently Windows loses about 1-2 minutes every week, which is why I have to manually log in every weekend and adjust the time to the correct time.

Is there a way I can manually adjust time drift to correct for this behaviour? There is a clear, constant drift - the clock is e.g. never ahead, and always delayed by roughly the same amount.

Comment: Is that specific server the only one without a network connection? i.e. could you set up a different server as an NTP time source and have this server sync from it?

Comment: Keep in mind that having the clocks on all the machines agree with one another and ensuring the time is accurate are essentially two different but related problems. If you solve one, you invariably end up having to solve the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following PowerShell one-liner will do it:

```
Set-Date (Get-Date).AddMinutes(2)
```

So set a scheduled task to run a powershell script with that command. You might need to [set the powershell execution policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) to run PowerShell scripts on your machine.

Naturally, this assumes your clock drift is as accurate as you claim

Answer (score 4):

GPS is the typical solution for machines that need time sync but have no external network connectivity. There are various software applications, both free and commercial, that can use a GPS receiver to sync the system time (search for "gps windows time sync" and you'll find a number of them). If you'd prefer an embedded device you can also find a number of devices that package up the entire GPS receiver into an Ethernet-attachable NTP server.

I don't have personal experience with either solution so I'm not going to make any specific recommendations. There are quite a number of offerings in both spaces out there, though.

Comment: That is a bit of overkill in my case...

Comment: Bear in mind that you can get a USB GPS receiver for sub-$50 and use a piece of free software and never have to worry about time drift again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reach another server in your local network that has internet access, you can set it up to sync to that server:

```
w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:server_with_internet /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes

w32tm /resync
```

Verify with https://time.is